# Why does the button last added to the container occupy the whole panel?

Tags: java, swing

I tried to add a series of buttons to the container of a frame. But I found that the last button added to the container always occupy the whole screen instead of at the correct position. How can I fix this problem?

Here is the code used to add these buttons:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        button[i] = new JButton();
        container.add(button[i]);
        button[i].setText(NAME[i]);
        button[i].setBounds(WIDTH-OFFSET_EDGE-bd.w, OFFSET+i*(bd.h+bd.gap), bd.w, bd.h);
        button[i].addActionListener(handler);
        button[i].setVisible(true);
    }
```

The container is get as following:

```
Container container = this.getContentPane();
```

The main class is the subclass of JFrame:

```
public class SimpleTextDemo extends JFrame
```

Now my solution is to use an extra button which is not visible so that the useful buttons can be at their correct location. But it seems that this method is **QUITE** stupid...

Comment: What is the layour manager for your container?

Comment: try setting the null Layout: in JFrame `setLayout(null);`

Comment: because the default layout is BorderLayout which has that behavior

Comment: Don't use a NullLayout, since this kind of Layout becomes very difficult to handle later on. Rely on Box, Border-LayoutManagers, etc. and you will be able to create advanced GUIs without any problems.

Comment: Oh that's true. It's the problem of default layout. I set it to `null` and the problem is solved. So is it more convenient to use border layout rather than null with `setBounds`? @My-Name-Is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default layout for `JFrame` is `BorderLayout`. If you add button to `JFrame` than it will occupy whole container. Change your layout using `setLayout` method.

Answer (score 1):

In java the default layout is set to the container is **`BorderLAyout()`** To add them properly you'll have to explicitly mention the position of the button to be added. All of these buttons you are adding will be added to the center. Finally all of'em are getting overlapped. To avoid this you can give them positions like `CENTER` , `EAST`, `WEST`, `NORTH`, `SOUTH`.

The reason for displaying only last button is all of'em are getting overlapped.